# Python programming on chromebook

Tags: python, google-chrome, command-line, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I got a dell Chromebook recently, running chromeOS but back on my old pc running Windows there was a Command Prompt, so I could write a script in notepad and then as long as I had Python installed I could run it. I want to know how to do that with a Chromebook either something online or something similar to the Command Prompt but on chromeOS.

I need to know how to run a complete script using something besides an interactive shell on chromeOS. A good answer will be a good help for me.

Comment: You can install Python using [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), although you will need to enable developer mode for this. For more information see [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64201789).

Answer (score 5):

There are three general methods of developing on a chromebook:

1. **Online/Cloud services**, i.e: https://www.juliabox.com
2. **Extension with Native code (or transpiled)**, i.e: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python/nodpmmidbgeganfponihbgmfcoiibffi?hl=en-US
3. **Developer mode**, i.e:
   https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton